# Group vectors with different range using clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a list of vectors of the form with repeated values also

```
([2.0 3.0] [2.0 4.0] [2.0 4.0] [2.0 12.0] [2.0 23.0] [2.0 6.0] [2.0 8.0] 
 [1.0 5.0]p [1.0 9.0] [2.0 8.0] [2.0 16.0] [2.0 19.0] [2.0 13.0]
 [2.0 18.0] [1.0 23.0] [2.0 24.0] [2.0 22.0] [2.0 33.0] [2.0 27.0]
 [1.0 29.0] [2.0 32.0] [1.0 35.0] [2.0 39.0])
```

I want to group them to different ranges using second value in the vector.

like grouping in ((1-5)(6-10)..)

The result here should be with repeated values also

```
(([2.0 3.0] [2.0 3.0] [2.0 4.0] [2.0 4.0] [1.0 5.0])
 ([2.0 6.0] [2.0 8.0] [2.0 8.0] [1.0 9.0])
 ([2.0 12.0] [2.0 13.0])
 ([2.0 16.0] [2.0 18.0] [2.0 19.0])
 ([2.0 22.0] [1.0 23.0] [2.0 23.0] [2.0 24.0])
 ([2.0 27.0] [2.0 29.0])
 ([2.0 32.0] [2.0 33.0] [1.0 35.0])
 ([2.0 39.0]))
```

When using map,group-by it is not considering the repeated values, only giving distinct. I want all the repeating values also to be grouped.

Comment: Are the two code blocks in your question the input and desired output of the expression you are trying to write?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Yess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(->> '([2.0 3.0] [2.0 4.0] [2.0 4.0] [2.0 12.0] [2.0 23.0] [2.0 6.0] [2.0 8.0] 
       [1.0 5.0] [1.0 9.0] [2.0 8.0] [2.0 16.0] [2.0 19.0] [2.0 13.0]
       [2.0 18.0] [1.0 23.0] [2.0 24.0] [2.0 22.0] [2.0 33.0] [2.0 27.0]
       [1.0 29.0] [2.0 32.0] [1.0 35.0] [2.0 39.0])
     (group-by (comp #(Math/ceil (/ % 5)) second))
     (sort-by first)
     (map second))
```

first group by the result of rounding up the second number divided by 5
then sort the map by its keys (a map is also a list of key-value tuples)
then map `second` over that to only get the collected values for each key

Answer (score 2):

You could use `group-by` with a function that calculates the bucket.

```
(defn bucket [v]
  (Math/ceil (/ (second v) 5)))

(defn my-grouping [vs]
  (-> (group-by bucket vs)
      (map (range 1.0 8.0)))) ; quick range hack, should calculate from input
```

I do not see how this should give only distinct values.

(I left the calculation of the correct range as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: Can I know how you defined 'v' and 'vs' here

Comment: when I defn bucket it says no matching method ceil. But I know ceil is used like (int (Math/ceil (/ 3 2))). I am new using bucket.

Comment: @joey yeah his `Math/ceil` call was incorrectly used. His last line also only works if your input has the constraint of the second number not going over 40

Comment: `v` is a single of your vectors, `vs` is the input list.

Comment: there is no calculation of the range necessary. just give back all the groups.

Comment: @BrandonH: except that that would leave out empty groups.  I don't know what the expectation is here.